# Vertica-Tableau error Multiple commands cannot be active

Tags: tableau-api, vertica

We have dataset in Vertica and Tableau is querying the data (4 Billions record) from vertica for dashboard as shown below :

[image: Tableau Dashboard]

All list and graphs are separate worksheets in tableau and using same connection to Vertica DB. Each list is a column in DB and list is descending order of # count of items in dataset's respective column. Graph also same as list but calculated in slightly different manner. Start Date and End Date is date range for Data to be query like data connection filter which will restrict the query to fixed amount of data example past week, last month, etc.

But I get this ERROR :

> Vertica][VerticaDSII] (10) An error occurred during query preparation: Multiple commands cannot be active on the same connection. Consider increasing ResultBufferSize or fetching all results before initiating another command.

Is the any workaround this issue or any better way to do this

Comment: Just a thought: if I am not mistaken, tableau uses ODBC, and there is a Threading parameter in ODBC config (at least under Linux). If it exists, could it help to set it?

Comment: I am not sure, my understanding was if the data connection is not listed in tableau native connections then we can use ODBC to connect SQL datastore. Please correct me if I have mistaken this. But let me try this too as per mentioned her [link] (http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/customizing-odbc-connections)

Answer (score 1):

you'll need a TDC file which specifies a particular ODBC connection string option to get around the issue.

The guidance from Vertica was to add an ODBC Connect String parameter with the value “ResultBufferSize=0“. This apparently forces the result buffer to be unlimited, preventing the error. This is simple enough to accomplish when building a connection string manually or working with a DSN, but Vertica is one of Tableau’s native connectors. So how do you tell the native connector to do something else with its connection?

Native Connections in Tableau can be customized using TDC files

“Native connectors” still connect through the vendor’s ODBC drivers, and can be customized just the same as an “Other Databases” / ODBC connection. In the TDC files themselves, “ODBC” connections are referred to as “Generic ODBC”, which is a much more accurate way to think about the difference.

The full guide to TDC customizations, with all of the options, is available here although it is pretty dense reading. One thing that isn’t provided is an example of customizing a “native connector”. The basic structure of a TDC file is this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<connection-customization class='genericodbc' enabled='true' version='7.7'>
<vendor name='' />
<driver name='' />
<customizations>

</customizations>
</connection-customization>
```

When using “Generic ODBC”, the class is “genericodbc” and then the vendor and driver name must be specified so that Tableau can know when the TDC file should be applied. It’s much simpler for a native connector — you just use the native connector name in all three places. The big list of native connector names is at the end of this article. Luckily for us, Vertica is simply referred to as “vertica”. So our Vertica TDC framework will look like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<connection-customization class='vertica' enabled='true' version='7.7'>
<vendor name='vertica' />
<driver name='vertica' />
<customizations>

</customizations>
</connection-customization>
```

This is a good start, but we need some actual customization tags to cause anything to happen. Per the documentation, to add additional elements to the ODBC connection string, we use a tag named ‘odbc-connect-string-extras‘. This would look like

```
<customization name='odbc-connect-string-extras' value='ResultBufferSize=0;' />
```

One important thing we discovered was that all ODBC connection extras need to be in this single tag. Because we wanted to turn on load balancing in the Vertica cluster, there was a second parameter recommended: ConnectionLoadBalance=1. To get both of these parameters in place, the correct way method is

```
<customization name='odbc-connect-string-extras' value='ResultBufferSize=0;ConnectionLoadBalance=1;' />
```

There are a whole set of other customizations you can put in to place to see how they affect performance. Make sure you understand the way the customization option is worded — if it starts with ‘SUPRESS’ then giving a ‘yes’ value will turn off the feature; other times you want to set the value to ‘no’ to turn off the feature. Some of the other ones we tried were

```
<customization name='CAP_SUPPRESS_DISCOVERY_QUERIES' value='yes' />
<customization name='CAP_ODBC_METADATA_SUPPRESS_PREPARED_QUERY' value='yes' />
<customization name='CAP_ODBC_METADATA_SUPPRESS_SELECT_STAR' value='yes' />
<customization name='CAP_ODBC_METADATA_SUPPRESS_EXECUTED_QUERY' value='yes' />
<customization name='CAP_ODBC_METADATA_SUPRESS_SQLSTATISTICS_API' value='yes' />
<customization name= 'CAP_CREATE_TEMP_TABLES' value='no' />
<customization name= 'CAP_SELECT_INTO' value='no' />
<customization name= 'CAP_SELECT_TOP_INTO' value='no' />
```

The first set were mostly about reducing the number of queries for metadata detection, while the second set tell Tableau not to use TEMP tables.

The best way to see the results of these customizations is to change the TDC file and restart Tableau Desktop Once you are satisfied with the changes, then move the TDC file to your Tableau Server and restart it.

**Where to put the TDC files**

Per the documentation ”

For Tableau Desktop on Windows: Documents\My Tableau Repository\Datasources
For Tableau Server: Program Files\Tableau\Tableau Server\\bin
Note: The file must be saved using a .tdc extension, but the name does not matter.”

If you are running a Tableau Server cluster, the .tdc file must be placed on every worker node in the bin folder so that the vizqlserver process can find it. I’ve also highlighted the biggest issue of all — you should edit these using a real text editor like Notepad++ or SublimeText rather than Notepad, because Notepad likes to save things with a hidden .TXT ending, and the TDC file will only be recognized if the ending is really .tdc, not .tdc.txt.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the taableau resolved my issue which was giving same error.